# Is there a way to make the correct toggled legends appear when downloading?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, legend, c3.js

I am using a c3 chart. I have a button to download it using canvg. I also have it toggle bars when legends are clicked. The download works and so do the toggles.

The only issue in the downloads is that I can either always show the legends (even if the bars they correspond to aren't being shown) or as soon as I toggle a legend the legend never appears again in the downloads (although it does on the chart itself).

What I would like is for the legends to only appear if their corresponding bars are actually being shown. I also don't want the legends to be hidden if their bar is being shown. (Legend Shown <=> Bar Shown kind of relationship)

I had issues with IE in the past so following https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2528 the display is 'Block'.

```
var string = ".c3-legend-item-hidden";//hides legends that are unselected in the download. Will KEEP them hidden even if retoggled :( 

d3.selectAll(string).each(function() {
    var element = this;
    var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < computedStyle.length; i++) {
        var property = computedStyle.item(i);
        element.style[property] = computedStyle.getPropertyValue(property);
    }
});

//removing this section makes all legends appear permanently regardless of whether the bar does
```

Expected: [a graph that has the correct bars and legends shown in the downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u88HW.png)

Actual:

(with code segment) [hidden legends that do not reappear when needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9DLy.png)

(without code segment) [legends that are never hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFDT0.png)

Update: Just to clarify, this works when converting the graph to a downloaded svg file (adding xmlns etc.), just not when using canvg and downloading to a png file (which is what I need it to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the computed style, manually set the styles you need.

This solution worked for me ('hidden' legends are slightly visible but it is now identical to my actual chart which is all I personally needed):

```
var string = ".c3-legend-item-hidden";

d3.selectAll(string).each(function() {
 //this.style['visibility']='hidden'; // uncomment this out and it will completely hide the legend if that is what you want
 this.style['opacity']= 0.15; 
 // set opacity as 0 to make the legend transparent to the point you can't see it (if that is what you want) 
 // or 0.15 to make it like the chart (as done here and in c3.css)
});
```

The computed styles give a lot more styles than you need and can override the styles you want.